# Asymptotic solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I have the following system of ODEs
$$
-4 (u a(u)+1) f'(u)=2 f(u) \left(u a'(u)+a(u)\right)+\left(u \left(3 a(u)^2+\frac{1}{4}\right) a'(u)+\left(a(u)^3+\frac{a(u)}{4}\right)\right),$$
$$a'(u)=\frac{1}{2} u f'(u),$$
$$a(0)=-1/2,
f(0)=0.$$

I need to find the behaviour of solutions at $u\rightarrow\infty$. Numerical experiments indicate that $f(u)\approx 3/8$ and $a(u)\approx -1/u$. But how can it be rigorously shown? I would be even happy to be able to show that $\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}a(u)=0.$ How to achieve that?

These equations have some relevance for Hubbard model of strongly correlated system (2-sites case). $-1/2\le a(u)\le 1/2$ implies that some approximate method fulfils the Pauli exclusion principle.

Comment: Is there some Hamilton or Euler-Lagrange formalism behind that system, or are there other conserved quantities? That would help in reducing the degrees of freedom at infinity, as the conserved expressions remain so also at infinity.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Unfortunately no. These equations are derived from the diagrammatic perturbation theory and the generalised Kadanoff-Baym Ansatz. Exact solution of the model also exists. According to it $a(\infty)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equation can be completely integrated. I a first step only using the first equation one can combine
$$
-2(ua(u)+1)f'(u)=\frac{d}{du}\left[2(ua(u)+1)f(u) + u\left(a(u)^3+\frac{a(u)}4\right)\right]
$$
Using also the second equation this results in
$$
C = 2a(u)^2+2f(u)+2(ua(u)+1)f(u) + u\left(a(u)^3+\frac{a(u)}4\right)
$$
With the initial conditions at $u=0$ we get $C=\frac12$.

Multiply the first equation with $f(u)$ and integrate, or reversely consider
$$
\frac{d}{du}\left[2(ua(u)+1)f(u)^2+uf(u)\left(a(u)^3+\frac{a(u)}4\right)\right]
=
uf'(u)\left(a(u)^3+\frac{a(u)}4\right)
\\=
2a'(u)\left(a(u)^3+\frac{a(u)}4\right)=\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{a(u)^4}2+\frac{a(u)^2}4\right)
$$
giving another first integral. Together these should be sufficient to compute values for the limits $f_0$ and $a_{-1}$ of $f(u)$ and $ua(u)$ for $u\to\infty$, under the empirical assumption that they exist and that $a_0=a(\infty)=0$.

---

The remaining system is
$$
\frac12=\frac94a_{-1}+4f_0\iff a_{-1}=\frac{2-16f_0}9\\
-\frac{3}{32}=2(a_{-1}+1)f_0^2+f_0\frac{a_{-1}}4
$$
which can be reduced to a cubic equation in $f_0$
$$
-\frac{27}{8}=8(11-16f_0)f_0^2+f_0(2-16f_0)=-128f_0^3+72f_0^2+2f_0
$$
This has its only real root at $f_0=0.64914270034929$, which is not the measured value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going through everything.

Comment: From the 2 algebraic equations, using that $a(\infty)=0$ I am getting $f/2-2f^2=-3/32$, which indeed leads to $f(\infty)=3/8$! So the question is how to establish rigorously that $a(\infty)=0$.